# Default value for a struct parameter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

How to initialize an optional paramerer for a structure type in C# ?
Is it possible in .NET 4.5?

```
string Foo(string myArg, KeyValuePair<string, string> myOptionalArg = ???)
{
     // todo
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can initialize the optional argument to any compile time literal value that is of the appropriate type.  For `KeyValuePair` the only compile time literal that is of that type (at least in any version of C# that currently exists) will be `default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)`.

Comment: Note that the values of a default ValueType created this way has each field initialized to their default values. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475(v=vs.71).aspx